# How to have a NSCollectionView item have dynamic height based on text field

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a NSCollectionView which presents items in a list.

[image]

my layout is defined by

```
private func configureCollectionView() {
    let flowLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()

    flowLayout.itemSize.width = self.view.frame.width
    //flowLayout.itemSize.height = 50
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 8
    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
    view.wantsLayer = true
}
```

When a long peice of text is entered as an item, I am trying to get the item height for that 'cell' to grow/expand with the content of the text.
I have setup my contsraints using AutoLayout and I fairly certain that it is setup correctly for this, but my item height remains fixed at 50 (I can't tell where this is getting set).

I am trying to take advantage of

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize
```

But I'm not having much luck with this either as I don't know how to best figure out what the Size should be (the height in this case)

Any suggestions on this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [sizeThatFits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428902-sizethatfits) with your desired width and a big enough height

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSSize {

    let string = strings[indexPath.item]
    let size = NSTextField(labelWithString: string).sizeThatFits(NSSize(width: 400, height: 800))

    return NSSize(width: 400, height: size.height > 80 ? size.height : 80)
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea. `sizeThatFits` uses  `intrinsicContentSize` by default, so you could use that for a shorter version, so:  `let size = NSTextField(labelWithString: string).intrinsicContentSize()`

Comment: Sweet... that was feeling intimidating to figure out and this was plug and play - thanks!